# where synchronization needed?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class sample1
{
    private static Map m = new HashMap();
    //....
    //.....
    //
    public void fun(String str1, String str2, sample2 s )
    {
        String str = str1 + str2 + s.getName();
        String value = m.get(str);
    }
}

public class sample2
{
    private String name;
            // ......
            // ........
            pubic String getName()
             {
                  return name;
             }
}
```

Here my question is where exactly the variables (arguments of function fun) like str1, str2 and s (sample2 object) are stored, in heap or stack?

Comment: @ Szilágyi Donát yes. Sorry.

Comment: There is a captalized `Sample2` and a lower-case `sample2`. Do they refer to the same class, is it a typo? Is this class immutable?

Comment: I would recommend reading Effective Java.  It's a book that will help your java code skills.  It will cover things like synchronization in a much better detail.

Comment: @Kurtymckurt Thanks for the suggestion. My only doubt here is where exactly the function arguments like str1, str2, s will be getting stored either in heap or thread stack. It would be great if you can answer that. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Any objects created with **new** are all heap memory.  Strings have an implied new since you can allocate them inline. 
`String str = "Hello World!";` 
http://www.ehow.com/info_8697974_heap-vs-stack-java.html

Answer (score 3):

You will never have any synchronization failure with str1 and str2, because those variables are strings, and the string class is immutable in Java.

Comment: what abt s (sample2 object)? where it be stored?

Comment: s if a field of class sample2 (syntax is not very conventional here for Java, usually a getter and a setter is provided). Anyway, s is a string, the value of a string is immutable, but the field s can be reassigned. You can see that as changing the value of a pointer to another string. An object is stored on the heap, so instances of sample2 will be stored on the heap.